# Qual a lógica por trás dessa função?

Tags: python, if, for

Por que o resultado do `L1` é: [2, 3, 4] em vez de [3, 4]?

```
def remove_dups(L1, L2):
    for e in L1:
        if e in L2:
            L1.remove(e)

L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L2 = [1, 2, 5, 6]
remove_dups(L1, L2)
print(L1)
```

Testei no Python Tutor e por algum motivo o segundo passo do `for` é no valor 3. Isso não faz sentido pra mim.

Comment: Outra alternativa é utilizar subtração de sets com: `L1 = list(set(L1) - set(L2))`

Comment: Ao remover elementos do array L1 você está quebrando o índice. Isso deveria gerar um erro explicito, mas não sei como o python trata isso. O correto é usar while, ou seja, faça enquanto existir a ocorrencia de L1 em L2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando cria um `for` usa um iterador, que controla o andamento da coleção. Quando você remove o primeiro elemento, o segundo passa ser o primeiro, o terceiro passa ser o segundo e assim continua. Portanto após a primeira passagem do laço a lista fica assim:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

E o iterador que estava em 0 passa para 1 na segunda passagem, aí a verificação é do número 3, que não está em `L2`, nada é removido, e depois o mesmo que 4.

Você não pode mudar o objeto de uma coleção durante uma interação impunemente. O mais correto aí seria fazer uma cópia ou usar outro algoritmo.

O que você está fazendo é (o que está pro trás do algoritmo do `for`):

```
def remove_dups(L1, L2):
    i = 0
    while i < len(L1):
        if L1[i] in L2:
            L1.remove(L1[i])
        i += 1

L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L2 = [1, 2, 5, 6]
remove_dups(L1, L2)
print(L1)
```

E o correto seria algo assim, apesar de ainda ter risco se houver alguma manutenção no código:

```
def remove_dups(L1, L2):
    i = 0
    while i < len(L1):
        if L1[i] in L2:
            L1.remove(L1[i])
        else:
            i += 1

L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L2 = [1, 2, 5, 6]
remove_dups(L1, L2)
print(L1)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4M65wJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bbmbsdaz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/Distinct.py).

Answer (score 2):

A [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288238/5878) explicou claramente que o problema na lógica implementada foi de alterar a estrutura que está sendo iterada e seus exemplos não poderiam ser mais didáticos, então gostaria apenas de acrescentar uma forma resumida das soluções:

```
def remove_duplicados(l1, l2):
    return [i for i in l1 if i not in l2]
```

Assim, a função retornará uma nova lista com os elementos de `l1` que não pertencem à `l2`.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [1, 2, 5, 6]

print(remove_duplicados(l1, l2))  # [3, 4]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/CrazyBubblyProblems) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/3ga8Fs)</sup>

Algumas vantagens nesta solução são:

1. Ao substituir os colchetes por parenteses no retorno, a função retornará um gerador, o que pode economizar memória;
2. Não é necessário criar cópias das listas de entrada;
3. As listas de entradas permanecem intactas (pode ser útil em alguns casos);
4. Solução legível;

**Comentários**:

Quando à economia de memória citado no item 1, tem-se duas observações: a) a economia de dá pelo fato de, ao substituir os colchetes por parênteses, o retorno da função deixa de ser uma lista e passa a ser um gerador; deste modo, não se tem a lista final armazenada em memória, dado que o gerador calcula cada item conforme sua utilização (*lazy 
 calculation* ou *call-by-need*). b) as referências aos objetos de entrada permanecem o mesmo *dentro* do gerador, não criando uma cópia dos mesmos; isto é, mesmo depois que o gerador for definido, qualquer mudança nas listas de entrada afetará o gerador.

Com colchetes, o retorno é uma nova lista:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 4]

def remove_duplicados(l1, l2):
    return [i for i in l1 if i not in l2]

z = remove_duplicados(x, y)

print(type(z))  # <class 'list'>

# Apenas para demonstrar a saída:
print(list(z))  # [1, 3, 5]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BestNoxiousObservation) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/TYyijd) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/bbb69ab00055aabdd7c07e4ba14d2ee5)</sup>

Com parenteses, o retorno é um gerador:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 4]

def remove_duplicados(l1, l2):
    return (i for i in l1 if i not in l2)

z = remove_duplicados(x, y)

print(type(z))  # <class 'generator'>

# Apenas para demonstrar a saída:
print(list(z))  # [1, 3, 5]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/NippyDimpledButton) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/aL7fG6) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/e14ec450075c1857399bd595a75c0eaa)</sup>

Como a referência das listas permanecem as mesmas, qualquer alteração nelas será refletida no resultado do gerador:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 4]

def remove_duplicados(l1, l2):
    return (i for i in l1 if i not in l2)

z = remove_duplicados(x, y)

# Alteração em y:
y.append(3)

print(type(z))  # <class 'generator'>

# Saída de z modificada devido alteração em y:
print(list(z))  # [1, 5]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LimeFrozenTwintext) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/QJtGwm) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/e46b41bf8fafcf906a3e37ff19e05cb1)</sup>

Os itens 2 e 3 são complementares, pois se o problema demandar que as listas de entradas devem permanecer intactas após a execução da função, utilizando a *list comprehension* ou o gerador não será necessário criar uma cópia em memória da lista para modificá-la; o próprio retorno será uma nova lista apenas com os itens desejados.

Já o item 4 é bastante subjetivo, mas eu, particularmente, acho que a solução fica muito mais legível:

```
def remove_duplicates(source, reference):
    return (item for item in source if item not in reference)
```

Comment: Não entendi o primeiro *bullet*. O segundo você quer dizer que evita ter que fazer manualmente, mas não a cópia em si?

Comment: @Maniero A primeira referi-me ao fato de que, retornando o gerador, você terá efetivamente duas listas em memória: `l1` e `l2`; não três, considerando a lista que é retornada pela função. Quanto ao segundo, sim, manualmente, considerando que não seja desejado que as listas de entrada sejam alteradas pela função.

Comment: Ou seja, cria a cópia, existirá uma terceira lista, só não é explícito?

Comment: @Maniero Em relação ao primeiro item? Se for, não existe a terceira lista. Os valores só serão gerados quando o objeto (gerador) for iterado.

Answer (score 0):

O for do Python mantém um contador de onde ele está na lista, se o tamanho da lista reduz, então isso vai atrapalhar no contador, esse código funcionaria bem se o tamanho da lista não mudasse. O melhor de jeito de se fazer isso é clonar a lista.

Esse é um problema do livro **Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python: With Application to Understanding Data**